# Derivative of the energy functional

Tags: partial-differential-equations, functional-equations

$\rho$ is a probability measures on $\Omega$ and $\epsilon$ is a given energy as below:

$$\epsilon (\rho) = \int_{\Omega} \Big[\alpha U(\rho(x)) + V(x) \rho(x)\Big] \, \mathrm dx + \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega \times \Omega} \Big[W(x-y) \rho(x) \rho(y)\Big] \, \mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy.$$

My question is how to prove the derivate of $\epsilon$ with respect to $\rho$ is

$$\frac{\delta \epsilon}{\delta \rho} = \alpha U'(\rho) + V + W\rho.$$

This question is from the paper I'm reading: Primal Dual Method for Wasserstein Gradient Flows.
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10208-021-09503-1.

Comment: Please describe what you have tried, and what you don’t understand, so  it is clear what exactly you need help with.

Comment: I don't know how to get the derivative. I have tried the definition of derivative by computing $\epsilon ( \rho + h(x) ) - \epsilon( \rho )$ though Taylor expansion. By why there is no integration in the  derivative in this paper?

Comment: Start by replacing $\rho$ with $\rho+\lambda\eta$ and take the derivative with respect to $\lambda$.

Comment: In the present case, you have simply $\frac{\delta}{\delta\rho} \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}$, as well as $\frac{\delta\rho(x)}{\delta\rho(x')} = \delta(x-x')$, where the last $\delta$ is a Dirac delta.